# React - not able to access latest props value inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Actually trying to access props inside the setInterval but it's not giving the latest value. Please find the below.  From the parent component, I am passing time and updating time after 1 ms initially it will be null.

In child component after 2 ms i am trying to access latest value from the props but its holds the older value which is null.

Please find the code below

```js
function ChildComp(props) {

  const checkTime = () => {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(props.updatedTime);
      }, 2000);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkTime();
  }, [])
  return(<div>child render: Time is {props.updatedTime}</div>)
}


function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTime((prev) => new Date().getTime());
    }, 1000)
  }, []);
  
  return(<div> App <ChildComp updatedTime={time} /></div>)
}




ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Thanks in advance. Happy coding!!

Comment: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks mate. but i am not looking for setting state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd don't want to use state because it looks to be the far easier solution. `setInterval` [seems to be very unpredictable](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Note: you should be passing in `props.updatedTime` as a dependency to the `useEffect`. But, now, because you know that the time is changing every second you can keep a count within state and just trigger the condition in the effect when it reaches 2.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function ChildComp(props) {

  // Set up state to keep count
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {

    // Increase the count
    setCount(count + 1);

    // When it reaches 2, log the time, and
    // reset the count
    if (count ===  2) {
      console.log(props.updatedTime);
      setCount(1);
    }

  // Pass in the time as a dependency
  }, [props.updatedTime]);

  return (
    <div>child render: Time is {props.updatedTime}</div>
    );

}

function App() {

  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(false); 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().getTime());
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  if (!time) return <div />      

  return(<div> App <ChildComp updatedTime={time} /></div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. But actually i need to use inside setInterval because I need calculate minute difference.

Comment: The things is you're using hooks so you need to refect the changes from the parent with the dependency. But every time the time changes you're calling `checkTime` again, a new interval is running., and it's causing problems. If you're sure you're getting data from the parent every second, just keep track of that.

Comment: thanks. but actuall problem is i need to access props latest value inside the setinterval. the code given is just sample

Comment: You should read the documentation in that link in my answer. It's possible to get it working, it just takes a lot more effort.

Comment: useEffect(() => { }, [props.updatedTime]); actually this helped me to solve this problem. thanks andy

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to follow [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68125589/6514790) by Andy. but if you want to continue using your current approach here is the solution.

You need to add `props.updatedTime` dependency in ChildComp `useEffect` array, so that whenever `updatedTime` props time changes `checkTime` should re-run.
And you need to clear the existing `setInterval` function if it's already executing.

```js
function ChildComp(props) {
  const intervalId = React.useRef(null)
  const checkTime = () => {
      intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(props.updatedTime);
      }, 2000);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    checkTime();
    // clear setInterval, if any
    return ()=>clearInterval(intervalId.current)
  }, [props.updatedTime])
  return(<div>child render: Time is {props.updatedTime}</div>)
}


function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTime((prev) => new Date().getTime());
    }, 1000)
  }, []);
  
  return(<div> App <ChildComp updatedTime={time} /></div>)
}




ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```